# Issue with php form: button input not triggering if statement

Tags: php, html

As stated above, when I try to send a form using php my if statement is not being triggered and the variable is not being set to my desired value.

**Relevant PHP:**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){


    if(isset($_POST['time_pickedm']) == "9:00"){
            $timepicked = "09:00:00";   

        } 
    }
```

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
<input type="button" class="<?php echo $buttoncolour ?>" name= 'time_pickedm' value = "9:00">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong, try:

```
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){


        if(isset($_POST['time_pickedm']) && $_POST['time_pickedm']== "9:00"){
            $timepicked = "09:00:00";

        }
    }
```

EDIT:
I think i found it!

in your html you have 2 buttons, so the time_pickedm is not going to your php. try replacing button for text:

```
<input type="text" class="<?php echo $buttoncolour ?>" name= 'time_pickedm'     value = "9:00">
```

Comment: I've tried this but the if statement still doesn't get called

Comment: @GeorgeSmith can you echo $_POST['time_pickedm'] or var_dump the $_POST before the if?.

Comment: echo $_POST['time_pickedm'] before the if produced an undefined index error

Comment: @GeorgeSmith and thats why your if is not returning true. Did you var_dump the $_POST, so you can check?

Comment: var_dump produces: array(0) { }

Comment: @GeorgeSmith Then your problem is not in your PHP. Your script is not getting the POST.

Comment: any suggestions on potential issues with the html form above?

Comment: @GeorgeSmith yeap look at the updated response! The problem is in your HTML.

Comment: I don't know your complete code but maybe you can use the same input as submit. Depends on your form and what are you trying to do.

Comment: almost there, that called the if statement, but I need the input as a button rather than a text box

Comment: <input type="submit" class="<?php echo $buttoncolour ?>" name= 'time_pickedm' value = "9:00"> and remove the other button

Answer (score 0):

You if condition invalid .If `time_pickedm` is present in array is always true .

its just like `if(true == "9:00")`

So Change to separate validate the condition

```
if(isset($_POST['time_pickedm']) && $_POST['time_pickedm'] == "9:00")
```

Comment: The `$a` variable in this answer should be replaced by `$_POST`.

Comment: could you evaporate what is not working.And what is problem ?

Comment: when I try that,  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ gets called but the if statement doesn't, and my variable doesn't get set to 9:00 and just stays as false

Comment: simply check `print_r($_POST);exit();` on top of the first line code.See the param is shown or not

Comment: that produces "Array()"

Comment: That's right.Its contain your param  of `time_pickedm`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: `that produces "Array()"` have `time_pickedm` key value or any text like this with array

Comment: copy paste `that produces "Array()"`

Comment: when I put print_r($_POST);exit(); above my php code, "Array()" got printed to the screen

Comment: For empty the dont have any param passed with `$_POST` os do with `inpu type="text"` or `input type="hidden"` like @Renzo Ezagui  answer